# What does aria-haspopup do?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrapping

I'm learning how to create navigation bars and dropdowns in Bootstrap 4, and instead of "data-target" attribute, I noticed "aria-haspopup = 'true'". Can you guys explain what this line does, and what values I can use for it? This is the full line of the code:

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="responsiveNavbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`aria-haspopup`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-haspopup) is not part of Bootstrap 4 but part of the [Accessible Rich Internet Applications (WAI-ARIA)](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1), W3C recommendation.

According to this recommendation the [`aria-haspopup`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-haspopup) attribute:

> Indicates that the element has a popup context menu or sub-level menu.
>
> This means that activation renders conditional content. Note that ordinary tooltips are not considered popups in this context.
>
> A popup is generally presented visually as a group of items that appears to be on top of the main page content.

the goal of the [`aria-haspopup`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-haspopup) attribute and of WAI-ARIA in general is to :

> allow assistive technologies to convey appropriate information to persons with disabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The aria-haspopup attribute indicates the availability and type of interactive popup element that can be triggered by the element on which the attribute is set.